# Function with `return`

Tags: javascript, prototype

Looking at the `foo` function on `Bar.prototype`:

```
  Bar.prototype.foo = function() {
    return console.log("Foo");
  };
```

What's the difference between

```
  Bar = function(name) {
         ...
         this.foo();
        };
```

and

```
  Bar= function(name) {
         ...
         return this.foo();   // note the 'return'
       };
```

Comment: In this case nothing, since `console.log` returns `undefined`, which is the same as not having a `return` statement at all.

Comment: what's the point of returning `this.foo()` if the function returns `Unit/void`, i.e. nothing.

Comment: Good point, @RocketHazmat - http://jsfiddle.net/9GLGz/. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first `Bar` function returns `undefined`, which is the default return value of a function in javascript.

The second `Bar` function returns the result of the `this.foo` function, which in turn appears to return the result of `console.log`, which again is `undefined`.

So they both return `undefined`, but they do take a different path to get that `undefined` value.